# Why the conditional operator in C does not work in my case?

Tags: c

i have this snippet of code

```
 int8_t startPage = ( ((uint8_t)(ceilf( (float)CurrentY / 8))) - 1);
 /* variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false*/
 startPage<0 ? 0:startPage;
```

if the `CurrentY` is NULL then the `startPage` is -1. 
But pages cannot be negative.

So I try to check it and if startPage is negative to set it as NULL.

But I have a warning `statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]`

and the code does not work. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The value from `startPage<0 ? 0:startPage;` is not used so the compiler warns you.

You could do something like the following:

```
startPage = (startPage < 0) ? 0 : startPage;
```

This sets `startPage` to `0` if it is less than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Result of the expression `startPage<0 ? 0:startPage;` is not assigned to a variable, so it is not used.  Thus, the compiler is warning you that there is a `statement with no effect`

Instead,

```
startPage = startPage < 0 ? 0 : startPage;
```

will work.  Though, this is more readable if you write:

```
if (startPage < 0) {startPage = 0}
```

Comment: If I write `startPage<0 ? startPage=0:startPage=startPage;` the I have a compiler error.

Comment: `startPage = startPage < 0 ? 0 : startPage;` will work. You can't assign inside a true clause of ternary operator. Though, this is more readable if you write `if (startPage < 0) {startPage = 0}`

Comment: I've incorporated the comments into the answer, as it was an answer -- the question was rhetorical.